# Проблема с Picasso

Tags: java, android, picasso

При вызове `Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(captchaImg).into(img);` выдает исключение мол `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.`
Я понимаю, что ему не хватает `ImageView`, но я ему передал её, объявил, а он всё равно видит как `null`, почему?

Передавал в основной `main_layout`, отображается, а в `AlertDialog(captcha_layout)` когда пытаюсь передать ссылку на img... видит как null. Может как-то не верно работаю с `AlertDialog`?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String url;
private String captchaImg;
private ImageView img;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView)

    btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new ShowDialogAsyncTask().execute();
        }
    });
}

private class ShowDialogAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Важное сообщение!")
                    .setView(R.layout.captcha_layout);
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(captchaImg).into(img);
        }
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Вызов onPostExecute()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        txt_percentage.setText(accesToken);
        btn_start.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

captchaImg - содержит uri изображения, тут проблем нет, подгружает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А отладчик показывает, что в `onPostExecute(...)` `img == null`?

Comment: Да, img == null

Comment: А в `onCreate(...)` он не `null`?

Comment: Тоже null...но только мне стоит объявить ImageView в main_layout так сразу же отображается и перестает быть null

Comment: Как я понимаю, он просто не видит ImageView в captcha_layout, хотя сам layout прикрепляется к AlertDialog

Comment: Так Вы не там ищите Ваш `ImageView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь все понятно, ваше imageView не в том layout что нужно, вы его ищите в activity_main.xml, а оно в captcha_layout.xml. Сделайте следующее:

```
View alertDialogView =   LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.captcha_layout);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Важное сообщение!")
                .setView(alertDialogView );
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
      alert.show();
        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(captchaImg).into((ImageView)alertDialogView.findViewById(id));
```